# How to replace a string with the user input in its designated spot - hangman

Tags: python, replace

```
displayed_word = ["-"*length]

#how do you write the guess in the designated spot in hangman?? and to replace the "-" ]
        designated_spot = s.find(guess)
        how_many = s.count(guess)
        print(f"the word had {how_many} of your guess in it")
        print(designated_spot)
        newletter = s.replace(guess, designated_spot)
        print(newletter)
```

I know a did a lot wrong here but i dont know what to do and how to write it.

I tried to do replace but i realised you couldnt use an integer and the integer is designated_spot and fhsdjkfsh

also s is the random.choice of my list

So I am trying to replace a user input aka "guess" in the designated spot where the guess fits in the random choice that python has generated from a list. As in change the "-" in its designated spot with the letter that the user guessed when the letter that is guessed is in the random word that the computer has generated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I gotta go with the bot on this one. It's hard to understand what you mean. I think you mean that on the print(designated_spot) line you just want to write print(guess) or what do you mean please clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
word = "apple" # example output from your list
displayed_word = "-"*len(word) # make a string the same length of the word that shows guessed letters

def make_guess(s: str, guess: str, displayed_word: str) -> str:
        # convert the displayed word to a list so that it is mutable (allows us to change characters)
        displayed_word = list(displayed_word)

        # loop through the string you are guessing, s, one character at a time.
        for i, letter in enumerate(s):
            if letter == guess: # if the current letter in s matches the guess, reveal that letter.
                displayed_word[i] = letter

        return "".join(displayed_word) # finally convert the displayed word back into a string.

displayed_word = make_guess(word, "p", displayed_word) 
print(displayed_word) # outputs: "-pp--"
displayed_word = make_guess(word, "e", displayed_word) 
print(displayed_word) # outputs: "-pp-e"
```

Check the documentation for [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) for information about how to use `str.replace`, as it doesn't replace characters at a specific index as you might have misunderstood, I hope this helps.

Comment: It works for everything else but, when in the code when it says "return." The computer states "can only be used within a function."

Comment: If you aren't familiar with functions, I recommend learning how they work: [here is a brief overview](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp). `make_guess` is an example of a function. It outputs the new `displayed_word` using `return` (this sends data back after the function is complete.)